# Unable to locate object with href in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
<a href="https://URL/documents/TermsOfUse.pdf" tabindex="6" target="_blank" class=""> Terms of Use </a>
```

I'm unable to locate the object using linkText. Can anyone help me how to locate the object for this?

I have tried :

```
@FindBy(linkText=" Terms of Use ")
```

But its failing to locate the object.

Comment: Paste your HTML please.

Comment: Provide more info. Code and website where you are doing will be helpful.

Comment: Paste your HTML please. looks like space issues

Comment: Do you need more info? If one of (or both) the answers below have helped you, please click accept.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
@FindBy(partialLinkText = "Terms")
WebElement termsOfUse;
```

Or

```
@FindBy(linkText= "Terms of Use")
WebElement termsOfUse;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use xpath `contains`.

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//a[contains(text(), 'Terms of Use')]")
```

[xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp) has many more advantages such as `and` and `not`, etc.